# How to sync keyboard with server in unity-3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a game where the users inputs (button presses, keyboard inputs, mouse movements etc) are sent to the server. When the server gets it, it uses those to update the players position, and send the new position back to the client.

I wanted to make a generic class that reads the mouse movements and key presses from the keyboard and send those to the server.

However I cant seem to figure out a good way to read the key pressed from the keyboard, because the unity key functions seems to require asking if a particular key was pressed like Input.GetKey(KeyCode.SHIFT), so basically I would have to have a line for every possible key press which is totally crazy.

Also what if the user hits multiple key like SHIFT+Z, or mashes all of the keys on the keyboard?

I only want client to send RPC to server if the key pressed was different from the one pressed last time, to save bandwidth.

Anybody have an idea? I'm using C# in unity-3D

Thanks

Comment: Do you care about all the keys or just some of them?

Comment: All of the keys, because I cant never tell which ones I will need in the future. I found this Input.inputString this has a string array containing all the keys pressed, this is what I was looking for. But it doesnt contain the other keys like shift, ctrl, alt, or the arrow keys, but I fond a way to solve that also. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force way to do this as you describe *without* creating a call for every individual input is to iterate over the `KeyCode` enum. Something like this:

```
KeyCode[] keyEnums = (KeyCode[])System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode));
List<KeyCode> newDown = new List<KeyCode>();
List<KeyCode> newUp   = new List<KeyCode>();
for(int enumIdx=0; enumIdx<keyEnums.Length; enumIdx++)
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(keyEnums[enumIdx]))
    {
        newDown.Add(keyEnums[enumIdx]);
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(keyEnums[enumIdx]))
    {
        newUp.Add(keyEnums[enumIdx]);
    }
}
```

Then ship the `newDown`/`newUp` Lists to your server.